# Python MDP Policy

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to implement a 4 dimensional race-car problem using [a famous MDP library for python](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/python/mdp.html).

We have a race-car in a 2 dimensional track.

When I say 4 dimensional problem, I mean that each STATE is (x,y,vx,vy), meaning: position (x,y) and SPEED (vx,vy). SPEED is either 0 or 1 (for each axis), so the number of states is finite and small.

There's a starting state, and one or more goal states.
When you hit a "wall", you return to the initial state.

Since I want to encourage a solution with a few steps as possible, each passable block has a "-1" reward, a wall has "NONE" (like the GridMDP example), and the goal has "0".

An ACTION is 2 dimensional (a,b), meaning acceleration for axis x and for axis y accordingly. The actions are limited. The action list is finite and small and is:

```
[(0, 1), (-1, 0), (-1, 1), (0, -1), (0, 0), (1, -1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (-1, -1)]
```

I built a class, FourDimMDPClass that inherits from the MDP class, and makes the appropriate changes (similiar to what they did in the GridMDP class at the link above)

To make things easy for now, state transition is deterministic. Meaning, the T function returns the one desired state with probability 1 (or the starting state, if you hit a wall).

I solved the MDP using the provided value_iteration method, and then tried to get the right policy using best_policy method.

**My problem is this:**
For some reason, the returned policy is total nonsense.
There is one constant action that is returned for ALL states. This action is simply the first action in the action list.
When I change the order of the action list, the new first action is always returned.

This is what happens with a very simple and small track.

I've been trying to debug this many many hours now, with no progress.
I tried looking at all the values passed to the MDP mechanism, and they seem fine.

Help will be much appreciated.

Alex

P.S.
Raw data:

```
Current track:
#####
#   #
#&#*# 
#####

& is the starting point
* is the goal
# means wall (or obstacle)

& is at (1,1)
* is at (3,1)

states  set( [
(1, 1, 0, 1), (3, 2, 1, 0), (3, 1, 0, 1), (2, 2, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1, 0), (3, 2, 0, 1), 
(3, 1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 0, 0), (1, 2, 1, 1), (3, 1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 2, 0, 0), 
(3, 1, 1, 1), (1, 2, 1, 0), (2, 2, 0, 1), (1, 2, 0, 1), (3, 2, 1, 1), (2, 2, 1, 0), 
(3, 2, 0, 0), (2, 2, 0, 0)])    set


reward  {
(0, 2, 0, 1): None, (2, 2, 1, 1): -1,   (0, 3, 0, 0): None, (3, 1, 1, 0): 0, 
(4, 1, 1, 1): None, (0, 3, 1, 0): None, (1, 3, 0, 1): None, (3, 1, 0, 0): 0, 
(1, 1, 1, 1): -1,   (1, 2, 0, 0): -1,   (3, 0, 0, 1): None, (2, 0, 1, 0): None, 
(4, 2, 1, 1): None, (4, 1, 0, 0): None, (1, 2, 1, 0): -1,   (2, 0, 0, 0): None, 
(2, 3, 1, 1): None, (0, 0, 1, 1): None, (3, 3, 0, 1): None, (2, 1, 0, 1): None, 
(4, 1, 1, 0): None, (3, 2, 0, 0): -1,   (1, 0, 1, 1): None, (3, 2, 1, 0): -1, 
(0, 2, 1, 0): None, (0, 2, 0, 0): None, (0, 1, 1, 1): None, (0, 3, 0, 1): None, 
(1, 3, 1, 0): None, (3, 1, 1, 1): 0,    (4, 0, 1, 0): None, (1, 3, 0, 0): None, 
(2, 2, 0, 1): -1,   (1, 2, 0, 1): -1,   (4, 2, 0, 1): None, (2, 0, 1, 1): None, 
(2, 3, 0, 0): None, (4, 1, 0, 1): None, (3, 3, 1, 0): None, (2, 3, 1, 0): None, 
(1, 1, 0, 1): -1,   (3, 3, 0, 0): None, (3, 0, 1, 1): None, (1, 0, 0, 0): None, 
(3, 2, 0, 1): -1,   (4, 3, 0, 0): None, (1, 0, 1, 0): None, (0, 0, 0, 1): None, 
(4, 0, 0, 0): None, (2, 1, 1, 1): None, (0, 2, 1, 1): None, (0, 1, 0, 0): None, 
(4, 3, 1, 0): None, (4, 2, 0, 0): None, (0, 1, 1, 0): None, (4, 0, 0, 1): None, 
(1, 3, 1, 1): None, (4, 3, 1, 1): None, (2, 2, 1, 0): -1,   (4, 0, 1, 1): None, 
(2, 2, 0, 0): -1,   (0, 3, 1, 1): None, (3, 1, 0, 1): 0,    (2, 3, 0, 1): None, 
(1, 1, 1, 0): -1,   (3, 3, 1, 1): None, (3, 0, 0, 0): None, (4, 2, 1, 0): None, 
(1, 1, 0, 0): -1,   (1, 2, 1, 1): -1,   (3, 0, 1, 0): None, (2, 0, 0, 1): None, 
(1, 0, 0, 1): None, (0, 0, 1, 0): None, (2, 1, 0, 0): None, (4, 3, 0, 1): None, 
(0, 0, 0, 0): None, (2, 1, 1, 0): None, (0, 1, 0, 1): None, (3, 2, 1, 1): -1
}   dict



MDPSolution {
(1, 1, 0, 1): -4.68559, 
(2, 2, 1, 1): -4.68559, 
(3, 2, 0, 1): -4.68559, 
(3, 1, 1, 0): -3.6855900000000004, 
(3, 1, 0, 0): 0.0, 
(1, 1, 1, 1): -4.68559, 
1, 2, 0, 0): -4.68559, 
(1, 2, 1, 0): -4.68559, 
(2, 2, 1, 0): -4.68559, 
(3, 2, 0, 0): -4.68559, 
(2, 2, 0, 0): -4.68559, 
(3, 2, 1, 0): -4.68559, 
(3, 1, 0, 1): -3.6855900000000004, 
(1, 1, 1, 0): -4.68559, 
(1, 1, 0, 0): -4.68559, 
(1, 2, 1, 1): -4.68559, 
(3, 1, 1, 1): -3.6855900000000004, 
(2, 2, 0, 1): -4.68559, 
(1, 2, 0, 1): -4.68559, 
(3, 2, 1, 1): -4.68559
}   dict



MDPPolicy   {
(1, 1, 0, 1): (0, 1), 
(3, 2, 1, 0): (0, 1), 
(3, 1, 0, 1): None, 
(2, 2, 1, 1): (0, 1), 
(1, 1, 1, 0): (0, 1), 
(3, 2, 0, 1): (0, 1), 
(3, 1, 1, 0): None, 
(1, 1, 0, 0): (0, 1), 
(1, 2, 1, 1): (0, 1), 
(3, 1, 0, 0): None, 
(1, 1, 1, 1): (0, 1), 
(1, 2, 0, 0): (0, 1), 
(3, 1, 1, 1): None, 
(1, 2, 1, 0): (0, 1), 
(2, 2, 0, 1): (0, 1), 
(1, 2, 0, 1): (0, 1), 
(3, 2, 1, 1): (0, 1), 
(2, 2, 1, 0): (0, 1), 
(3, 2, 0, 0): (0, 1), 
(2, 2, 0, 0): (0, 1)
}   dict
```

Main functions:

T gets a state and an action, and returns the next state

```
def T(self, state, action):

    if (action==None):
        new_vx = state[2]
        new_vy = state[3]
    else:
        new_vx = state[2]+ action[0] 
        new_vy = state[3]+ action[1] 

    myProbStateList = []

    nextState = self.go(state, (state[0]+new_vx,state[1]+new_vy,new_vx,new_vy))
    myProbStateList.append((1.0,nextState))       

    return myProbStateList
```

go gets state, and new_state. If the route from state to new_state is legal, it returns new_state. otherwise, returns the initial state.

```
def go(self,state, new_state):
    "Return the state that results from trying to going in the new state."

    #state1 = utils.vector_add(state, acceleration)

    myInitState = (self.init[0],self.init[1],0,0)

    old_loc = (state[0],state[1])
    new_loc = (new_state[0],new_state[1])

    if ((new_state in self.states) & self.track.isFreeWay(old_loc,new_loc) & self.track.in_bounds(new_state[0],new_state[1])):
        return new_state
    else:
        return myInitState
```

Comment: You need to ask a more specific question I think. Debugging code without seeing the source is difficult.

Comment: Hi Paul, you are correct. I will add more info.

Comment: By the way, the code for the library I'm using can be found on the [link I mentioned](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/python/mdp.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved it.

Notice that all states that include negative speeds are not present at the STATES set, and also not preset at the REWARD dictionary.

This was due to a faulty initialization process.